# Clear All Documents and Data With Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My app downloads and display `GIF`s from the Internet in `UIImageView`s. The `GIF`s don't need to be cached/saved at all. However, the app takes up lots of storage on the iPhone with Documents & Data being enormous.

I'd like to be able to clear the Documents and Data folder each time the user opens the app. Is this possible to do with `Swift`?

Comment: If you are talking about the folder inside app's sandboxed folder, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Are you storing your downloaded `GIF` files anywhere in phones directory?

Comment: I'm talking about when you go into Settings on iPhone and then tap Storage and then tap the App's Name, it says Documents & Data with hundreds of megabytes sitting in it. How do I clear that?

Comment: @KarthickSelvaraj I'm downloading the GIFs with [this extension](https://github.com/KrisYu/GifExt/blob/master/GifExt.swift)

Comment: You are not supposed to use that to download files from the internet, (See the important text here) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init

Comment: @Pochi does this effect data storage?

Comment: I just need to figure out how to clear documents and data, it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: @JohnnyD Yes it affects the data storage, read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension you use uses the following code:

```
Data(contentsOf: url)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init

This method will cache stuff in the system cache.

If you want to keep using that extension you should modify that code to use this one instead:

```
init(contentsOf:options:)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407864-init

And pass "uncached" as an option to avoid the cache.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata.readingoptions/1412417-uncached

However I think that extension is poorly written, for instance, you should only use this method to load SHORT local files, for bigger files a stream is needed, for network requests you shouldn't be using it at all.

> Important
>
> Don't use this synchronous method to request network-based
>   URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread
>   for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user
>   experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated. Instead,
>   for non-file URLs, consider using the 
>   dataTask(with:completionHandler:)  method of the NSURLSession class.
>   See URL Session Programming Guide for details.

---

```
Data(contentsOf: url, options: .uncached)
```

Comment: `Data.init(contentsOf: url, options: .uncached)` still resulting in lots of storage in documents and data

Comment: Did you delete and reinstalled the app once? or you mean, you expect your current app to be cleaned of the cached stuff?